# Not able to get correct response using requests.session()

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to scrape a booking page of a movie in bookmyshow site. I am using requests library for this. My code is:

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
rs = s.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/serv/getData?cmd=GETSHOWINFO&vid=MOMV&ssid=1112")
print(rs.status_code)
rt = s.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/serv/doSecureTrans.bms")
print(rt.status_code)
print(rs.text)
```

This is the code for getting the source code of the page, i am using. For the first page i am getting 200 as response and then for the second page is also giving 200 response. when i print the source code i am getting "invalid request" as output. what could be the error?

Comment: that's what the server answers to your request. you can check it by accessing to https://in.bookmyshow.com/serv/doSecureTrans.bms

Comment: but when i inspect this element, in response, i can see the xml code for seating arrangement. The main problem i am facing is i am unable to get total number of seats available.